# Is there a difference between (eg) 'ListView' and 'generic.ListView'?

Tags: django, django-views

Please help clarify some basic concepts. Googling leads to answers about the difference between two different views, eg, ListView vs DetailView, but not where my confusion is:

The official Django docs has two import versions:

```
from django.views import generic
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
```

And

```
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
class ArticleListView(ListView):
```

Are the two interchangeable? I have had the following *seemingly* with no ill effect:

```
from django.views import generic
class IndexView(ListView): # insteald of `generic.ListView`
```

Comment: No, both refer to the same class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are the two interchangeable?

**Yes**, both will refer to the *same* class. The first one is sometimes used if you want to import a lot of items from the `django.views.generic` module, and thus do not want to list these.

Furthermore it is sometimes used to avoid "*name clashes*" where you import two different things with the same name. For example the `django.forms.CharField` and `django.db.models.CharField` are two *different* types, then it can help to import one through an alias, or import the module and thus reference to it with `models.CharField` or `forms.CharField`.

Comment: Does `from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, DeleteView` fall into the same category? What about `from django.views.generic.base import View`--is it the same as all the other Django views (except for name clashes)?

Comment: @YCode you can import these views from two places because the `generic` module's `__init__` imports them and adds them to `__all__`, so both `from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView` and `from django.views.generic import CreateView` will import the _same_ view.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat That makes sense! So is `from django.views.generic.base import View` the same as `from django.views import generic`? I followed Django official docs to `django.views.generic.base`, but that led to the `redirect` view.

Comment: @YCode how would `from django.views.generic.base import View` and `from django.views import generic` be the same thing? `View` is a class in `django.views.generic.base` while `generic` is a module in `django.views`. If you meant `from django.views import View` and `from django.views.generic.base import View` (and even `from django.views.generic import View`) then yes they are the same (so many places to import the same things from ;) ).

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I was indeed confused. Thanks for the clarification!